# How to add matrices saved as a list in a dataframe, by group?

Tags: r, dataframe

Is it possible to add matrices, saved as a list in dataframe cells, by group. Like the code below? The result should be in matrix format, not the sum of the matrix elements.

```
#create data
mtx <- matrix(data=1:9,ncol=3)
df <- data.frame(gp=c("a","a","b","c"),data=NA)
df$data[1] <- list(mtx)
df$data[2] <- list(mtx)
df$data[3] <- list(mtx)
df$data[4] <- list(mtx)

#sum matrices by group
df2 <- df %>% 
  group_by(gp) %>% 
  summarise(total=list(sum(data)))

#what the result should look like
df3 <- data.frame(gp=c("a","b","c"),total=NA)
df3$total[1] <- list(2*mtx)
df3$total[2] <- list(mtx)
df3$total[3] <- list(mtx)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `split` the dataset by *gp* and use `+`with `Reduce` in `lapply` to sum matrices, saved as a list in dataframe cells, by group.

```
lapply(split(df$data, df$gp), Reduce, f=`+`)
#split(df$data, df$gp) |> lapply(Reduce, f=`+`) #Alternative
#$a
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    2    8   14
#[2,]    4   10   16
#[3,]    6   12   18
#
#$b
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
#
#$c
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    4    7
#[2,]    2    5    8
#[3,]    3    6    9
```

A try using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(gp) %>%
  summarise(total = list(Reduce(`+`, data)))
```

Comment: Thanks GKi, but I'd like to keep the matrix format, I should have said so in the question.

Comment: I have changed it, to keep the matrix format. Is this closer now to what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted, thanks for the help. I guess there isn't a tidyverse solution.

Comment: I do not use tidy. But luckily tidy does not disable or overwrite all base functions. So this solution will also work with the tidy package.

Comment: If possible please can you add a tidy version to your answer?

Comment: I never use dplyr. Based on your given way this might work.